# Order by query is returning different ordering

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Order by query is returning different ordering, why?

```
SELECT class FROM table WHERE class != "" ORDER BY class ASC
```

**Result:**

```
411101000010

*411102000010* (err)

411101000000

411101000020

411101000050
```

Why?

Comment: Is the column `class` a VARCHAR or a NUMERIC one? Some values may have spaces at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your *class column* is `varchar` so to sort the column class you need to convert it to int by casting it as INT or using this trick `ORDER BY ABS(class)`.

```sql
SELECT class FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(class AS INT) ASC
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b371c/6)

### Notes:

Use Single quotes `class != ''` when you dealing with strings. Double quotes generally aren't used in **SQL**, but it deponds on database you're using(MySQL accept both single and double quotes).

The default ordering in `ORDER BY` clause when nothing has been explicitly specified is `ASC`.so you can omit the order asc since it is the default.